# Speeding up VBA for loop in Word

Tags: performance, vba, loops, ms-word

My code gets the start of certain heading 1's but its painfully slow! 
Is there anything that could be done to speed it up?
And also why is this the case? From experience in Java I know "for loops" to be very fast in comparison.
My only idea is that it has to iterate through OOXML instead of text so there is far more to go through.. Or does word just have less 'processing power?
Should a different loop be used for this type of case in VBA? Or even something else all together?

```
For Each OO In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If InStr(OO.Style, "Unnumbered") = 0 Then
        If InStr(OO.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "PRODUCT") > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "OVERVIEW") > 0 Then
            Header1(1) = OO.Range.start
            MsgBox (Header1(1))
        ElseIf InStr(OO.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "SAFETY") > 0 Then
            Header1(2) = OO.Range.start
            MsgBox (Header1(2))
        ElseIf InStr(OO.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "PHARMACOVIGILANCE PLAN") > 0 Then
            Header1(3) = OO.Range.start
            MsgBox (Header1(3))
        ElseIf InStr(OO.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 _
                And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "EFFICACY") > 0 Then
            Header1(4) = OO.Range.start
            MsgBox (Header1(4))
        ElseIf InStr(OO.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "MINIMISATION") > 0 Then
            Header1(5) = OO.Range.start
            MsgBox (Header1(5))
        ElseIf InStr(OO.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "MANAGEMENT") > 0 Then
            Header1(6) = OO.Range.start
            MsgBox (Header1(6))
        ElseIf InStr(OO.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "REFERENCES") > 0 Then
            Header1(7) = OO.Range.start
            Header1(8) = OO.Range.End
            MsgBox (Header1(7))
            MsgBox (Header1(8))
            End If
    End If
Next OO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks to me like it's evaluating the same thing over and over again just going through one iteration of the loop.

This is, InStr(00.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 is evaluated every ElseIf.  As is Left(00.Range.Text, Len(00.Range.Text) - 1).  If the first If doesn't evaluate to True, then the next line does the same thing.  And the next.  And so forth.

Therefore my suggestions on speeding this up would be:

1 - Put a variable inside the loop before the If statements, that contains Left(00.Range.Text, Len(00.Range.Text) - 1), and change all your references to that comparisons in your If/ElseIf clause to that variable.

2 - InStr(00.Style, "Heading 1") > 0 is on every line.  Move that into a separate containing If, with the other InStr comparisons inside that If.

3 - Long ago I read that "< > 0" is faster than "> 0" for VB.  Not sure if that still applies to VBA.

4 - Arrange your If/ElseIfs so that the most likely match will appear before those that are less likely.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
Dim head1, x as Integer

For Each OO In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

If InStr(OO.Style, "Unnumbered") = 0 Then
    head1 = Instr(OO.Style, "Heading 1")

    if head1 <> 0 then
      x = Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1)

      If InStr(x, "PRODUCT") < > 0 And InStr(Left(OO.Range.Text, Len(OO.Range.Text) - 1), "OVERVIEW") <> 0 Then
        Header1(1) = OO.Range.start
        MsgBox (Header1(1))
      ElseIf InStr(x, "SAFETY") < > 0 Then
        Header1(2) = OO.Range.start
        MsgBox (Header1(2))
      ElseIf InStr(x, "PHARMACOVIGILANCE PLAN") < > 0 Then
        Header1(3) = OO.Range.start
        MsgBox (Header1(3))
      ElseIf InStr(x, "EFFICACY") < > 0 Then
        Header1(4) = OO.Range.start
        MsgBox (Header1(4))
      ElseIf InStr(x, "MINIMISATION") < > 0 Then
        Header1(5) = OO.Range.start
        MsgBox (Header1(5))
      ElseIf InStr(x, "MANAGEMENT") < > 0 Then
        Header1(6) = OO.Range.start
        MsgBox (Header1(6))
      ElseIf InStr(x, "REFERENCES") < > 0 Then
        Header1(7) = OO.Range.start
        Header1(8) = OO.Range.End
        MsgBox (Header1(7))
        MsgBox (Header1(8))
      End If
    End If
End If

Next OO
```

It's been a while since I've used VBA, so this may be a little off.

Comment: Okay Thank you very much and I'll try that!

Comment: Thank You very much! Your exact code is so much faster and only takes about 10 seconds compared to the 5 or so minutes before hand!

Comment: I'll see if I can tweak it even more to get it faster using a variable in the If statements

Comment: Yes, that's what I intended to put in there.  Also, if you are doing a case sensitive search, there may be room for improvement on the InStr lines.  Check to see if it's defaulting to a text compare or binary compare.  Binary is faster, however is case sensitive.

Comment: Code is revised to include moving Left() into a variable.